# Sourcing cable guide clamps - for multiple cables

Tags: cable

I'm looking for a cable guide clamp (for loss of a better word), but struggling to find any suitable ones online (similar style to below).

[image: 3 individual stainless steel-looking clamp-on cable guides, where each accommodates a single cable]

It is the component which you use to hold a brake/shift cable to the frame when the frame doesn't have any guides built into it. **Ideally metal, and capable of housing multiple cables (up-to 4)**. Is there another name for these pieces? And/or do you know where I can find some online (EU/DE)?

Comment: Tektro make them, and Dia Compe/ENE CICLO. They are also easy to find on ebay direct from China

Comment: https://problemsolversbike.com/products/brakes/clamp_on_cable

Comment: https://velo-orange.com/products/dia-compe-cable-housing-clips

Comment: A long established may have NOS.

Comment: Any known for clipping multiple cables? On the bottom bar I've got 2 gear and 1 brake cables with housing

Comment: @WilliamBakerMorrison these are traditionally used for clamping the rear brake outer to a top tube, so were only used on a single cable.  Finding ones capable of securing multiple could be a challenge, you may have to use one clamp per cable and offset them.  Or maybe design a "comb" that can be clamped down.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen anything like this designed to clamp multiple cable housing. There are clamp on cable housing stops if you want to run bare wire along your downtube or top tube, but that's a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an option for you.
[image]
Something like this appears to be available at amazon.de under "Cable Guide Brake Cable". You probably can get more than one clip on a zip tie.
There are options that use an adhesive rather than a zip tie.

Double cable clips are rare but can be found. They are usually plastic or thin sheet steel. Searching google.de with "bicycle double cable clips" turns up some options.

I've never seen, and can't find, clips for three or four cables.
If you route the rear brake cable down the top tube and the two gear cables on the down tube doubles would work - assuming a double diamond frame.